# How to parse email addresses in Google BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a table as below in BigQuery -

```
with temp as (
select "john.doe@company-Y.com" as email_id
union all 
select "hello.world@company-X.com" as email_id
)
select * from temp
```

I would like to generate 3 new columns (`firstname, lastname, company`) from the `email_id` field such that the output would be -

```
firstname, lastname, company
john         doe      company-Y
hello        world    company-X
```

Which BigQuery function can be used for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

There are really too many ways of doing this and below is quick (first came in mind) one:

```
#standardSQL
WITH temp AS (
  SELECT "john.doe@company-Y.com" AS email_id UNION ALL 
  SELECT "hello.world@company-X.com" AS email_id
)
SELECT 
  SPLIT(SPLIT(email_id, '@')[SAFE_OFFSET(0)], '.')[SAFE_OFFSET(0)] firstname,
  SPLIT(SPLIT(email_id, '@')[SAFE_OFFSET(0)], '.')[SAFE_OFFSET(1)] lastname,
  SPLIT(SPLIT(email_id, '@')[SAFE_OFFSET(1)], '.')[SAFE_OFFSET(0)] company
FROM temp
```

with result

```
Row firstname   lastname    company  
1   john        doe         company-Y    
2   hello       world       company-X
```

But really right solution will depend on nature and pattern your data has and obviously personal preferences, etc.

Another quick option would be

```
#standardSQL
WITH temp AS (
  SELECT "john.doe@company-Y.com" AS email_id UNION ALL 
  SELECT "hello.world@company-X.com" AS email_id 
)
SELECT 
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(email_id, r'^(.*?)[.@]') firstname,
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(email_id, r'\.(.*?)@') lastname,
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(email_id, r'@(.*?)\.') company
FROM temp
```

with same result

Just to extend a little  - so you see direction for improvements - for example if names are separated bu `.` or `-`

```
#standardSQL
WITH temp AS (
  SELECT "john.doe@company-Y.com" AS email_id UNION ALL 
  SELECT "hello.world@company-X.com" AS email_id UNION ALL
  SELECT "hello-world@company-X.com" AS email_id UNION ALL
  SELECT "hello@company-X.com" AS email_id
)
SELECT email_id,
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(email_id, r'^(.*?)[-.@]') firstname,
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(email_id, r'[-.](.*?)@') lastname,
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(email_id, r'@(.*?)\.') company
FROM temp
```

with result

```
Row email_id                    firstname   lastname    company  
1   john.doe@company-Y.com      john        doe         company-Y    
2   hello.world@company-X.com   hello       world       company-X    
3   hello-world@company-X.com   hello       world       company-X    
4   hello@company-X.com         hello       null        company-X
```

Comment: thanks Mikhail for covering different cases and providing solution to this question.